# How to bind dataset to datagrid in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am binding a dataset to datagrid in XAML using Object dataprovider.

Here is my code:

```
    <UserControl xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Pauspan_n_"  
         x:Class="UCitems"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="700" d:DesignWidth="1100">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="sizes" ObjectType="{x:Type my:Item_sizes}">

    </ObjectDataProvider>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="sizes2" ObjectInstance="{StaticResource sizes}" MethodName="Getsizes">

    </ObjectDataProvider>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Height="700" Width="1100">


    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="154" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="819,55,0,0" 
              Name="dgv_itemsizes" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="242"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource sizes2}}" ></DataGrid>
    </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

My dataset name is `Item_sizes` and the datatable name is `sizes`,
but datagrid shows nothing in it.

I think I may want something like this:

```
     Public Overridable Overloads Function GetSizes() As Item_sizes.sizesDataTable
        Me.Adapter.SelectCommand = Me.CommandCollection(0)
        Dim dataTable As Item_sizes.sizesDataTable = New Item_sizes.sizesDataTable()
        Me.Adapter.Fill(dataTable)
        Return dataTable
    End Function
```

Comment: Post the `Item_sizes.Getsizes()` method.

Comment: Where i found this method ??

Comment: i edit my question check it

Comment: In XAML you have `MethodName="Getsizes"` but the name of the method is `GetSizes` (first 's' is capitalized). Is that a typo here on OS, or do you have the same definition in your actual code?

Comment: No man it is not working till now after capitalizing the first 's'

Comment: Try binding with `DataView` in place of `DataTable`. You can get DataView by `dataTable.DefaultView`.